# Expression in regular expression python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to make a regular expression for formatting a text, in which there can't be a `{` character except if it's coming with a backslash `\` behind. The problem is that a backslash can escape itself, so I don't want to match `\\{` for example, but I do want `\\\{`. So I want only an *odd* number of backslashs before a `{`. I can't just take it in a group and lookup the number of backslashs there are after like this:

```
s = r"a wei\\\{rd thing\\\\\{"
matchs = re.finditer(r"([^\{]|(\\+)\{)+", s)
for match in matchs:
    if len(match.group(2)) / 2 == len(match.group(2)) // 2: # check if it's even
        continue
    do_some_things()
```

Because the group 2 can be used more than one time, so I can access only to the last one (in this case, `\\\\\`)
It would be really nice if we could just do something like `"([^\{]|(\\+)(?if len(\2) / 2 == len(\2) // 2)\{)+"` as regular expression, but, as far as I know, that is impossible.
How can I do then ???

Comment: counting number of backslashes is a NP-hard problem..

Comment: Beside the point, but to check if something's even, use modulo-2: `0 % 2 == 0`, `1 % 2 == 1`, `2 % 2 == 0`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches an odd number of backslashes followed by a brace:

```
(?<!\\)(\\\\)*(\\\{)
```

Breakdown:

- `(?<!\\)` - Not preceded by a backslash, to accommodate the next bit

  - This is called "negative lookbehind"
- `(\\\\)*` - Zero or more pairs of backslashes
- `(\\\{)` - A backslash then a brace

Matches:

```
\{
\\\{
\\\\\{
```

Non-matches:

```
\\{
\\\\{
\\\\\\{
```

Try it on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/5498s)

---

*This was partly inspired by [Vadim Baratashvili](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13501027/vadim-baratashvili)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61701059/4518341)*

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to not match the backslashs ? I would like to put everything in a lookbehind but Python don't want a variable-lenght text in a lookbehind. Also, this is a little bit dumb, because Python could just reverse the expression in the lookbehind (`(abc)+` would become `(cba)+`) and do as always but backwards...

Comment: @Bananasmoothii Yes, just use a non-matching group, `(?:\\\\)*`

Comment: I know that syntax, but I have a regex that looks like like `\{([^\{%]+)(%[^\{%]+)?(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\}` and I would like the first group to be blue and the second one to be green, but in "{a%b\\\\}", the backslashs stay black because they are either in the first either in the second group...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [this](https://regexr.com/548sj) as solution:
`([^\\](\\\\){0,})(\{)`

We can check that between the last character that is not a backslash there are 0 or more pairs of backslashes and then goes {if part of the text matches the pattern, then we can replace it with the first group `$1` (a character that is not a slash plus 0 or more pairs of slashes), so we will find and replace not escaped { .

If we  want to find escaped { we ca use this expression:
`([^\\](\\\\){0,})(\\\{)` - second group of match is  `\{`

Comment: Awesome. I just rearranged it to make it clearer. I can't get it to work though. It doesn't find any matches in the example.

Comment: @wjandrea if you add { with paired backslashes or without backslashes to the text, { will be replaced by an empty string and finded if we do not need to replace anything (then we have to process it as we need)

Comment: I think that's the opposite of what OP wants, but the question is not totally clear. I posted [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61702055/4518341) partly inspired by yours though, thanks!

Comment: @wjandrea or you can use `([^\\](\\\\){0,})(\\\{)` to find 
`\{
\\\{
\\\\\{
`

Comment: Why do you use `{0,}` instead of `*` ?

Comment: @Bananasmoothii There are no special reasons, they are interchangeable